# Capture a substring which is not present in the source string

Tags: regex, string, url-rewriting, pattern-matching

I want regular expression search and replace as follows:

- Input string ends with `images`, `videos`, `friends`

  - Output string contains the **matched** suffix
- Else

  - Output string contains the suffix `profile`

Example input/output:

- `/john-smith-images` -> `/user-images`
- `/john-smith-videos` -> `/user-videos`
- `/john-smith` -> `/user-profile`

I tried this regex which captures the suffix, if present:

```
/.+?(images|videos|friends)?$/
```

I am ***restricted to one regular expression*** and ***regular expression only solution***. I need to use this in mod_rewrite/IIRF/IIS URL rewrite.

Comment: Can we use javascript's replace syntax (in particular, the second argument as a callback)?

Comment: No, javascript/php/script/programming.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .replace(), consider using .match() or .test()  inside a conditional, and handling the non-matching case separately.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
text.replace(/[\w-]+(?=(images|videos|friends))/, 'user-').replace(/[\w-]+-(?!(images|videos|friends))\w*/, 'user-profile')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String#replace with callback like this:

```
var regexp = /.+?(images|videos|friends|)$/;
function cb ($0, $1) {
   r = $1 ? $1 : 'profile';
   return '/user-' + r;
}
console.log("/john-smith-images".replace(regexp, cb));
console.log("/john-smith-videos".replace(regexp, cb));
console.log("/john-smith".replace(regexp, cb));
```

**Output:**

```
/user-images
/user-videos
/user-profile
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/MVRcku